# Can I implement an override of a virtual function which gets as parameter a father class?

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual-inheritance

I am trying to override the `equal` method in the following code:

```
class object{
  int a;
public:
  virtual bool equal(const object& o) const{
    return this->a==o.a; // not sure if i can access private field (o.a) from one object function to the object o so it's another question
  }
};

class point: public object{
  double x;
  double y;
public:
  bool equal(const point& o) const override{
    return (this->x==o.x && this->y==o.y);
  }
};
```

I thought of overloading `operator==` and use it as a `friend` function but it would help me if I could do it somehow in this case...

Comment: If you add the special identifier `override` after the `point::equal` function (as in `bool equal(const point& o) const override { ... }`) then the compiler will tell you that you are not overriding anything.

Comment: What you want to do fails on a design level before any implementation. Suppose I hold an `object &` which refers to a `point`, and I call it with another `object` -- maybe a `square`. What happens? -- In the general case, a derived function may accept a wider argument set than its parent, but not a narrower one.

Comment: if it takes a different parameter types it isnt an overload

Comment: ohh, ok... thanks, some programmer dude

Comment: You can trivially try this, and get an error like _error: `bool point::equal(const point&) const` marked `override`, but does not override_. Did you?

Comment: There is no virtual inheritance here

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot, try adding `override`:

```
bool equal(const point& o) const override;
```

...and you get a compilation error:

> error: 'bool point::equal(const point&) const' marked 'override', but does not override

This is normal design for an object-oriented language, imagine the following:

```
object *p = new point();
object p2;

p->equal(p2);
```

`p->equal` would find `point::equal(point const&)` by virtual lookup but `p2` is not a `point`, it is an `object`, so what the compiler should do?

If you want to override `equal`, you could do the following:

```
bool equal(const object& o) const override {
    auto *p = dynamic_cast<const point*>(&o);
    if (!p) {
        return false;
    }
    return this->x == p->x && this->y == p->y;
}
```

...but maybe you should rethink your design instead of doing this?

Comment: @GuySadoun You could test if `o` is a `point`, return `false` if it is not, and then do the correct test, but this does not look like a good design for C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the signature of the equal method, it hides the parent rather than overrides it.  You could do something like this (room for efficiency improvement):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::boolalpha;

class object{
  int a;
public:
  object(int value) : a{value} {}
  virtual bool equal(object const& o) const {
    return typeid(*this) == typeid(o)
      && this->a == o.a;
  }
};

class point : public object {
  double x;
  double y;
public:
  point(int value, double xval, double yval) : object{value}, x{xval}, y{yval} {}
  bool equal(object const& o) const {
    return object::equal(o)
      && this->x == dynamic_cast<point const&>(o).x
      && this->y == dynamic_cast<point const&>(o).y;
  }
};

int main() {
  auto o1 = object{7};
  auto o2 = object{7};
  auto p3 = point{7, 8.0, 9.0};
  auto p4 = point{7, 8.0, 9.0};
  auto p5 = point{7, 8.1, 9.1};

  cout << boolalpha;
  cout << "o1 equal o2? " << o1.equal(o2) << "\n";
  cout << "o1 equal p3? " << o1.equal(p3) << "\n";
  cout << "p3 equal p4? " << p3.equal(p4) << "\n";
  cout << "p3 equal p5? " << p3.equal(p5) << "\n";
  cout << "o2 equal o1? " << o2.equal(o1) << "\n";
  cout << "p3 equal o1? " << p3.equal(o1) << "\n";
  cout << "p4 equal p3? " << p4.equal(p3) << "\n";
  cout << "p5 equal p3? " << p5.equal(p3) << "\n";
  cout << "---done---" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I particularly like the uncaught exception if the rhs isn't really a `point`.

Comment: True.  But if an exception is a thrown, then typeid failed.  And if you can't trust typeid... well, then things are in a bad way.

Comment: And I agree with Holt's comment "...but this does not look like a good design for C++".  Just because something can be done is independent from whether something should be done.

Comment: It will throw `std::bad_cast` if the `object` argument isn't really a `point`. It doesn't mean you have a general RTTI problem, just that you're making an unwarranted assumption about the dynamic type of your argument.

Comment: @Useless • the part of the code that checks to make sure both objects are the same type ensures that both objects really are the same type.  So doing a `p.equal(p2)` and p is a point, but p2 isn't really a point, will return false (and short circuit) before the dynamic_cast occurs.  If p2 isn't really a point, but the RTTI says it is a point...

Comment: I missed the typeid check in the base class. I'm not sure how I feel about that, but it doesn't help that we're both just guessing about the desired semantics.

Comment: it's just my second question in stackoverflow, I am a first-year student (CS) and it is unbelievable that the programmer community shares their knowledge like that. I thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of senses in which this is problematic.

Firstly, your existing code *definitely* won't work, and if you had tried the compiler would have told you so.

Let's examine why

```
object a{42};
point b{1.2, 3.4};
bool ab = a.equal(b);
bool ba = b.equal(a);
```

so, questions:

1. how should we calculate `ab`?

   OK, that one's easy: the `point` b *is* an `object`, so we call `a->object::equal(object const&)`.
2. how should we calculate `ba`?

   This one's harder.

   We can use `b->object::equal(object const &)`, which has the benefit of being symmetric (it's usually nicer if `a.equal(b) == b.equal(a)`.

   Or we could write an override, so we call `b->point::equal(object const &)`, and have it decide whether its argument object is *really* a `point`. (This is Holt's `dynamic_cast` solution).

For the last case, we could have an overload (instead of an override) so `point` has two `equal` methods, one taking an `object` (this can really be the base-class method) and one taking a `point`. However, this only works for static type.

```
class point : public object{
  double x;
  double y;
public:
  bool equal(const point& o) const {
    return (this->x==o.x && this->y==o.y);
  }
  using object::equal; // stop this being hidden
};
```

Now we have an overload rather than an override (so there's no point using `virtual` at all at this stage), we can write

```
point c{5.6, 7.8};
bool ba = b.equal(a); // uses b->object::equal(object const&)
bool bc = b.equal(c); // uses b->point::equal(point const&)
```

However, as soon as we start storing base-class pointers or references (which is the normal reason for using `virtual` in the first place), we lose the dynamic type information:

```
object &r = c;
bool br = b.equal(r); // uses object::equal(object const&)
```

If you need this case to use the dynamic type (ie, figure out that `r` really refers to a `point`), you need to use something like `dynamic_cast`. The code doesn't scale very nicely as the number of subclasses grows, but it's a lot simpler to implement for small cases than a full-blown Visitor.

Comment: thanks a lot, it was very useful for my understanding